# Regex with optional groups not working - \d is not working in the parenthesis (\d*%)

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to write regex for the following rules in which button (a,b,start) are the only field required, all other groups are optional but having problems. Some look-behind logic is also required which I am having problem with as well

- This regex is for a virtual game controller with buttons. Some of the buttons are "a", "b," and "start".
- Each button can have a duration appended, but it is not required. "a500ms" will press the A button for 500 milliseconds. "a1s" will press the A button for 1 second.
- Buttons can be pressed in sequence without spaces. "ab" presses A then B. "astart" presses A then Start.
- The parser syntax is as follows: (modifier) (button) (percentage) (percent symbol) (duration) (duration type) (appended)
- (button) is the only required group. Everything else is optional.
- If (percent symbol) does not have a (percentage) or (duration type) does not have a (duration), it's invalid
- A complete example utilizing the full syntax: "_start20%12ms+"
- This holds "start" for 20 percent for 12 milliseconds and appends a later input

Examples:

- "a600msb200ms" - valid
- "ams500b" - invalid since (duration type) ("ms") did not have (duration) ("500") before it
- "astart" - presses A then Start (this currently does not work in my regex, but it should)
- "b1sstart" - presses B for 1 second then start
- "b+a" - presses B and A simultaneously
- "_b a" - holds B then presses A

My regexp:

```
^(a|b|start)(\d*%)?(\d*(s|ms))?
```

Here is the test bed https://regex101.com/r/jGf0VR/3

### Problems

The regex is not working for me with the following problems

1. `(\d*%)?` - this group is not working, suppose to capture 500%, 200% but it is not working (yes tried it with backslash still does not work). The fact it should be optional but it is never taken as optional
2. `a200ms300s` - should be captured but it is not captured, similarly `a200s300ms`should also be captured
3. `a200ms200%` - should be invalid, I can't seem to fix this one primarily because of `(\d*%)?` is not working for me as highlighted in prob1

Comment: Your regexp only matches one button press, not a sequence.

Comment: It should match sequence also but I could get the first set of rules work.

Comment: If the number is required before `ms` or `%`, you should use `\d+` rather than `\d*`.

Comment: Yes, that is required. Also before (\d*%)?, immediate button press is required, i.e. a200%200ms ✔︎ but a200ms200% ✗ - this group does not match correctly btw, should be optional as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to match a string containing a single button press:

```
^(a|b|start)(\d+%)?(\d+(s|ms))?$
```

I changed `\d*` to `\d+` to indicate that at least one digit is required before `%` or `s|ms`. I added `$` at the end so it won't match if there's something extra after the match.

To match a sequence of them, put a group around everything except the anchors, and allow it to repeat.

```
^((a|b|start)(\d+%)?(\d+(s|ms))?)+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gDk90x/2)

Comment: Works perfect so far, but second line condition `a500ms50ms` which should pass is not matched.

Comment: Why should that pass? It has two durations, your spec only allows for one duration.

Comment: If you want to allow any number of durations, change `?` to `*`.

Comment: I need a little extra help. The regex captures only the last group, I need to captured all recurring groups, eg. in `b1sstart `, it should match b1s and start as two groups. Read the literature but could not get it done. Demo  https://regex101.com/r/gDk90x/5

Comment: A group can only capture one thing per match. You'll need to match each occurrence separately, but then you can't anchor it.

Comment: I want to make the entire match as one group and each recurring instance a second group but that did not work for me. I tried to use token ?: , that reduced groups but did not not solve the problem

Comment: You can't do that. A capture group can only capture one thing. If it's quantified, it will capture the first match.

Comment: What language are you using? Use its method for getting multiple matches, such as PHP `preg_match_all()` or Python `re.findall()`.

Comment: C#, that's what I think is the right approach but I thought may be if possible in this case.